# Asynchronous processing .NET SQL Server?

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, sql-server-2008-r2

After many years of programming, I need to do something asynchronously for the very first time (because it takes several minutes and the web page times out -- don't want the user waiting that long anyway).  This action is done by only a few people but could be done a few times per day (for each of them).

From a "Save" click on an ASP.NET web page using LINQ, I'm inserting a record into a SQL Server table.  That then triggers an SSIS package to push that record out to several other databases around the country.

So..

1. How can I (hopefully simply) make this asynchronous so that the user can get on with other things?
2. Should this be set up on the .NET side or on the SQL side?
3. Is there a way (minutes later) that the user can know that the process has completed and successfully?  Maybe an email?  Not sure how else the user can know it finished fine.

I read some threads on this site about it but they were from 2009 so not sure if much different now with Visual Studio 2012/.NET Framework 4.5 (we're still using SQL Server 2008 R2).

Comment: Read into using AJAX and possibly web methods -- sounds ideal for your situation...

Comment: Not necessarily.  If the user navigates away, there would be no mechanism remaining to see the result or check for errors.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally a bad idea to perform long-running tasks in ASP.Net.  For one thing, if the application pool is recycled before the task completes, it would be lost.

I would suggest writing the request to a database table, and using a separate Windows Service to do the long-running work.  It could update a status column in the database table that could be checked at a later time to see if the task completed or not, and if there was an error.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Service Broker on the SQL side; it'sa SQL Server implementation of Message Queueing.
Good examples [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/09/21/sql-server-intorduction-to-service-broker-and-sample-script/) and [here](http://blog.maskalik.com/sql-server-service-broker/scalable-webservice-calls-from-database)

What you do is create a Service Broker service and define some scaffolding (queues, message types, etc). 
Then you create a service "Activation" procedure which is basically a stored procedure that consumes messages from queue. This SP would receive for example a message with an ID of a record in a table, and would then go on and do whatever needs to be done to it, perhaps sending an email when it's done, etc.

So from your code-behind, you'd call a simple stored procedure which would insert the user's data into a table, and send a message to the queue with for e.g the ID of the new record, and then immediately return. I suppose you should tell the user upfront that this could take a few minutes and they'll receive an email, etc.

The great thing about Service Broker is message delivery is pretty much guaranteed - even if your SQL Server falls over right after the message is queued, when you bring it back up the activation SP will just kick off again, so it's very robust.